# Scrapy Spider - XPATH

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

can someone help me here? I'm not able to get the data from this page, I don't know if I did something wrong with xpath. Any suggestion?

```
import scrapy

class CatalogoAplusSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'catalogo_aplus'
    allowed_domains = ['www.aplus-automotive.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.aplus-automotive.com/index.php?pg=products&dil=pt&kategori_id=&marka=&model=&str=&grup=&aplusnumber=&oemnumber=&crossnumber=&sayfanum=0']

    def parse(self, response):
        for catalogo_aplus in response.xpath("//div[@class='urun-sonuclari-listesi']/table/tbody/tr/td"):
            yield{
                'cod_aplus': catalogo_aplus(".//div[@class='urun-sonuclari-listesi']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a").get(),
                'nome': catalogo_aplus(".//div[@class='urun-sonuclari-listesi']/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/a").get(),
                'fabricante': catalogo_aplus(".//div[@class='urun-sonuclari-listesi']/table/tbody/tr/td[4]/a").get(),
                'modelo': catalogo_aplus(".//div[@class='urun-sonuclari-listesi']/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/a").get(),
                'oem': catalogo_aplus(".//div[@class='urun-sonuclari-listesi']/table/tbody/tr/td[6]/a").get()
            }
```

When one of the fields has more than one value, how do I choose all of them? In some cases it has more than one OEM, I wanted to capture all available.

Example here

```
//div[@class='urun-sonuclari-listesi']/table/tbody/tr/td[6]/a
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant part of the page's source?

Comment: I didn't quite understand, what did you mean by relevant part?

Comment: Sorry if my comment wasn't clear, I mean the part(s) of the page's source which includes the elements that you're trying to select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select the data you may need to remove the `tbody` from your XPath. Usually this is the case when the original source code doesn't have this element, but the browser renders it anyway when you load the page.

```
"//div[@class='urun-sonuclari-listesi']/table/tr/td"
```

[Read more about this caveat here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/developer-tools.html#caveats-with-inspecting-the-live-browser-dom).

---

**For your second question, I'm not sure this what you are asking, but from what I understood:**

When you have a selector that returns multiple items and you want them all, you should use the `.getall()` method. That will return a list of strings with ALL the elements that selector found.

---

**Finally a tip:**

```
.xpath(".../tr/td[2]/a").get()
```

If you leave the selector like this, you will get the HTML value of that `<a>` node. If you want only the text you can use `/text()` or if you want the link `/@href` in the XPath.

```
.xpath(".../tr/td[2]/a/text()").get()
.xpath(".../tr/td[2]/a/@href").get()
```

[To learn more on using selectors.](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#id1)

---

### Edit:

*This is my answer to the follow-up question you posted as an answer bellow.*

I strongly suggest you read the [scrapy tutorial](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) and use the [scrapy shell](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html#using-the-shell) before writing the spider. Using the shell allows you to inspect the results of everything you are doing in real-time, so it makes it easier to see your mistakes.

```
 for catalogo_aplus in response.xpath("//div[@class='urun-sonuclari-listesi']/table"):
```

This is the same case we talked in your previous question. That XPath will select entire tables and there is ONLY ONE table in that path. So the return is ONE object. You won't really iterate over anything, because there is only one return.

I imagine that what you want is to iterate over the ROWS of the table, in that case the selector must select the ROWS (`tr` elements):

```
for catalogo_aplus in response.xpath("//div[@class='urun-sonuclari-listesi']/table/tr"):
```

*I removed `tbody` as mention above in this same answer*

Now for each iteration, the variable `catalogo_aplus` will be a Selector Object referencing a row in the table. Now you need to extract the data of each cell in the row

```
'cod_aplus': catalogo_aplus.xpath("td[2]/a/text()").get()
```

*`catalogo_aplus` is already referencing a `tr` so you need only to specify the context inside that node*

```
'oem': catalogo_aplus.xpath("td[6]/a/text()").getall()
```

*`getall()` because you want all the returns in this cell, not just the first.*

Comment: Hi Renato, I sent the message answering my question, here I wouldn't have enough characters, I don't know if I did it correctly. Thank you for your patience in helping me.

Comment: Hi Lucas, dont worry, we are all here to help each other. However, in the future, it's better to edit your question and add more information instead of writing the follow-up in an answer.

Comment: Thank you very much again, I will follow your suggestions! Now it worked and I also realized that I forgot to put .xpath here 'oem': catalogo_aplus ("td [6] / a / text ()"). Getall ()